# Difference between nonrestrictive relative vs participle clause

Tags: sentence

while I studied with Toeic textbook, I came across this question. In my opinion, two options are all possible, but only option 2 (which is) is correct in the answer sheet. Why is the option 1 (being) incorrect?

> The agenda, ___ available on the library's Web site, includes an information session about the proposed library building on the city's east side.

1. being
2. which is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use 'being' in that position as a link verb if an explanation or reason follows, e.g.:

> *The agenda, being available on the library's Web site, was visible to
> anyone who might be interested.*
>
> *The agenda, being available on the library's Web site, was no longer a
> secret.*
>
> *The agenda, being available on the library's Web site, was not printed on paper.*
>
> *The tower, being 500 metres tall, was visible all over the town.*

In your sentence, what follows is not connected with the fact of the agenda's presence in that way.

> 2. LINK VERB
>
> Being is used in non-finite clauses where you are giving the reason
> for something.
>
> *It being a Sunday, the old men had the day off.* [VERB noun]
>
> *Little boys, being what they are, might decide to play on it.* [VERB
> noun]
>
> *Of course, being young, I did not worry.* [VERB adjective]
>
> [Also VERB preposition]

[Being (link verb) (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/being)